# Extracting data from objects using Unsafe (bypassing the Security Manager0

Tags: java, memory-management, native, unsafe, bytebuffer

I am fully aware that I am doing is:
1) Unsafe, that I have no more guarantees, type safety, and that the `JVM` could therefore crash
2) That I could do similar operations using ByteBuffers or `JNI`
3) That Unsafe is an internal class and could well disappear.

I am doing this for experimentation purposes only and am aware of the consequences.

With this in mind, I am trying to extract the data from an array using Unsafe and reflection:

I first find the field offset of the array:

```
public long findFieldOffset(Event event) {
    try {
        Class cl = event.getClass();            
        Field data_field = cl.getDeclaredField("data");            
        data_field.setAccessible(true);
        long offset = unsafe.objectFieldOffset(data_field);            
        return offset;            
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;        
}
```

I also extract the base location of the array:

```
       int base = unsafe.arrayBaseOffset(byte[].class);
```

I subsequently try to extract the array from the class Event, and copy it to a buffer (`byte_offset` is the result of `findFieldOffset`).
In the code below, the first part is just a test function and prints out the correct string, whilst the second part extracts what should be the array, but when testing returns garbage unicode values:

```
                  /* Testing  */
                    active_buffer.getBuffer().position(1); 
                    active_buffer.getBuffer().put(event.getData()); 
                    active_buffer.getBuffer().position(1); 
                    active_buffer.getBuffer().get(tuple, 0, (int)tuple_size);
                    System.out.println("Test1: " + new String(tuple)) ;
                   /* Test1 prints out the correct string */

                    unsafe.copyMemory( (Object) event,  byte_offset  +  base, (Object) null, active_buffer.getAddress() + 1, tuple_size);
                    active_buffer.getBuffer().position(1); 
                    active_buffer.getBuffer().get(tuple, 0, (int)tuple_size);
                    System.out.println("Test2: " + new String(tuple)); 
                    /* Garbage unicode values gets printed*/
```

Can anyone see anything wrong with this code?

Comment: Its worth nothing that HotSpot turns many Unsafe "native" calls into intrinsic rather than using JNI. e.g. it can be just one machine code instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `data` is a field, it is either a primitive or a reference, in either case you cannot copy it somewhere and treat it as a `byte[]`

If `data` is a byte[] you need to treat this as the true object, not the Event.

Comment: Thanks. Good point. I now get 
Test1: name10000000000Bob000000000000YxzBUSPv
Test2: ??dname10000000000Bob000000000000YxzBUSPv
So it's a good start. Do you have any idea of how to access the memory location of the array directly (I could just do event.getData() and use that - which as you suggested works, but event.getData() is a fairly expensive call, so was hoping to get the memory reference directly)

Comment: If you just want to get the `data` field you can access it via reflection, you don't need to use an Unsafe. If you want to use Unsafe, you can get access to the reference, you don't need to copy the contents of the byte[]. If you want to copy the contents of a `byte[]` you can use normal System.arrayCopy() like any other `byte[]`

Comment: You only need to use Unsafe to copy data to/from direct/native memory which you don't appear to need.

Comment: I'm copying data to native memory, and was trying to avoid the cost of doing event.getData first (or obtain it by reflection), and then copyMemory. To access the reference, are you basically saying to use getLong at byte_offset?